# Scaling ComboBox Popup inside ViewBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm developing an UWP App and noticed ComboBox elements (just the popups) are scaling incorrectly when placed inside a ViewBox. Here's how it looks:

[image]

Also, the wrong elements are selected since the ComboBox detection seems to be off from the actual mouse position. The ComboBox is placed alongside other elements inside a grid (which is a direct child to the ViewBox). Everything else works properly and scales without stretch.

Is there any way to fix this while keeping the ViewBox?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Width="1920" Height="1280" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="50">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Test123"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Test456"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Test789"></ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

This is pretty much all I'm trying to do, I need the app to be resizable and only support a specific resolution (1920x1280). It needs to be adaptable to every possible Windows-scaling setting in some way though.

Comment: Hi, please include your code or XAML so we can help.

Comment: @CorentinPane Sorry, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [seems to be a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1187) recently introduced by the Windows team. One of the suggested fix in the linked post is to add an invisible rotation on the `ViewBox`:

```xml
<Viewbox>
    <Viewbox.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="0.001"></RotateTransform>
    </Viewbox.RenderTransform>
    <Grid Width="1920" Height="1280" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="50">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test123"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test456"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test789"></ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Surely it's disgusting, that's why Microsoft recommends to follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/responsive-design) to find alternative ideas (without the `ViewBox` that isn't supposed to be used to keep an app responsive).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Strange workaround but it fixed my problem.